# Basic Negationsfunction: not(true) to return false

Tags: javascript, function, boolean

With logical not operator, how do I make a function with one boolean argument to return `not(false)` to true and `not(true)` to false?

Comment: You can use the [logical not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)

Comment: Try `function negation(flag){ return flag.toString().length === 5; }`.

Comment: `const not = v => !v;`

Comment: much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function returnNot(val) {
return !val
}
```